# Let $1\lt k \in\mathbb{N}. $ Prove: $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{k}\lt ln(k) \lt 1+ \frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{k-1}$ using integration.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $1\lt k \in\mathbb{N}. $ Prove: $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{k}\lt ln(k) \lt 1+ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{k-1}$ using definite integrals.

Hey everyone. I've been trying to prove this statement by splitting the interval $[1,k]$ into $k$ intervals of 1 length, and approximating the definite integral $\int^k_1 (\frac{1}{x})dx $, but am having issues. I would be happy to get some help on this question. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried to draw all three functions?

Comment: You're on the right track. Make rectangles that are all below the graph, and make another set of rectangles that are all above the graph. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Samuel Thank you Samuel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Try fit in some rectangles (see @Samuel's comment)

[image]